# Why does addeventlistener() not work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to playing an animation when clicked on a button but it does not work.

I want to play the 'logo_animation' when the pricing_logo got clicked.What is the problem ?

```
id="pricing-div">
    <i id="pricing-logo" class="fa-solid fa-money-bill"></i>
    <div id="pricing-display-div">
        <img src="iphone-black.png" alt="" id="pricing-photo-div">
        <div id="pricing-text-div"><h1 id="pricing-text">Pricing</h1></div>
        <div id="pricing-storage-and-color-div">
            <div id="pricing-storage-div">
                <div id="pricing-storage-128-gb-button"><p id="pricing-storage-128-gb">128 GB</p></div>
                <div id="sep-div"></div>
                <div id="pricing-storage-256-gb-button"><p id="pricing-storage-256-gb">256 GB</p></div>
                <div id="sep-div"></div>
                <div id="pricing-storage-512-gb-button"><p id="pricing-storage-512-gb">512 GB</p></div>
                <div id="sep-div"></div>
                <div id="pricing-storage-1024-gb-button"><p id="pricing-storage-1024-gb">1 TB</p></div>
            </div>
            <div id="pricing-color-div">
                <div id="color-space-black"></div>
                <div id="sep-div"></div>
                <div id="color-gold"></div>
                <div id="sep-div"></div>
                <div id="color-silver"></div>
                <div id="sep-div"></div>
                <div id="color-purple"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
  var pricing_logo=document.getElementById("pricing-logo");
  pricing_logo.addEventListener("click",function(){
      pricing_logo.style.animationName="logo_animation";
      pricing_logo.style.fontSize="0vw";
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly does "does not work" mean? Does *anything* happen? Are there errors in the browser console?

Comment: @Pointy anything does not happen. I cannot click it.It works without a problem when I take it out of the addeventlistener().

Comment: What about errors in the browser console? Have you tried adding `console.log()` statements to the code, or perhaps using the debugger?

Comment: Oh and for the record, your browser is not broken and `.addEventListener()` does work when it is used properly.

Comment: @Pointy console.log() does not work either and there are no errors on the console.

Comment: It seems you did not include the `fa` CSS. As you have presented it, there is no button. Please make it reproducible.

Comment: @trincot what do you mean by fa?

Comment: It is referenced in your HTML: `fa-solid fa-money-bill`. This strongly suggests you intend to use "font awesome" styling, but it must be loaded.

Comment: @trincot I already did it. I can see it when I open the HTML file on the live server but I still can not click.

Comment: Please edit your question and create a runnable snippet (using the toolbar button) that includes FA and reproduces the problem. Currently your question has HTML that is broken at the start, and when fixed, it does not display a button. If we cannot reproduce it, we cannot help.

Comment: The code seems to work fine, once I took a guess at what you wanted your animation to do. Without the Font Awesome code, that "button" will be invisible; in the snippet I put text in the `<i>` element. When that's clicked, the animation runs. Note that setting the element height to 0 is not necessary, and in fact will make the animation reset back to an invisible button after it runs.

Comment: @Pointy: your last edit of the question adds code OP never posted based on a "guess" you've made trying to undestand this unclear question. With all due respect, I think you should have posted your "guess" as an answer instead of editing OP"s question.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette well you're right of course, I was fully expecting the question to be closed before I finished tinkering with it :)  In fact it should probably be closed anyway because the original code posted was mostly fine (even though the CSS was missing). The OP didn't really clarify what exactly was going wrong. If it was that the `@keyframe` setup was wrong, that wasn't ever posted!  I'll do as you suggest however.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version as a snippet with a guess (well not a guess so much as an example) for the CSS code necessary for animation:

```js
var pricing_logo = document.getElementById("pricing-logo");
pricing_logo.addEventListener("click", function() {
  pricing_logo.style.animationName = "logo_animation";
});
```

```css
@keyframes logo_animation {
    from { font-size: 0; }
    to { font-size: 18px; }
}

#pricing-logo {
    animation-duration: 5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="pricing-div">
  <i id="pricing-logo" class="fa-solid fa-money-bill">FA</i>
  <div id="pricing-display-div">
    <img src="iphone-black.png" alt="" id="pricing-photo-div">
    <div id="pricing-text-div">
      <h1 id="pricing-text">Pricing</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="pricing-storage-and-color-div">
      <div id="pricing-storage-div">
        <div id="pricing-storage-128-gb-button">
          <p id="pricing-storage-128-gb">128 GB</p>
        </div>
        <div id="sep-div"></div>
        <div id="pricing-storage-256-gb-button">
          <p id="pricing-storage-256-gb">256 GB</p>
        </div>
        <div id="sep-div"></div>
        <div id="pricing-storage-512-gb-button">
          <p id="pricing-storage-512-gb">512 GB</p>
        </div>
        <div id="sep-div"></div>
        <div id="pricing-storage-1024-gb-button">
          <p id="pricing-storage-1024-gb">1 TB</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="pricing-color-div">
        <div id="color-space-black"></div>
        <div id="sep-div"></div>
        <div id="color-gold"></div>
        <div id="sep-div"></div>
        <div id="color-silver"></div>
        <div id="sep-div"></div>
        <div id="color-purple"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code basically works. The main thing I did other than the CSS was to introduce content to that Font Awesome `<i>` tag so that there's something to click on.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably switching css property wrong since only entering animation name in css wouldn't work. Example of working animation in css:

```
.class {
animation: animationName 1s (duration) 1 (or once, how many times animation is played out)
}
```

So what you can do is to apply already created class with this keyframes animation as described above with properties that you need or change the `.style.animation`  property of element like that:

```
.addEventListener('click', () => {
const animationText = 'keyframes_name 1s forwards ease once'
element.style.animation = animationText
})
```

You can also add properties one by one from defined variables in your js.

There is also animate API in js which you can read on more here:
[MDN docs js animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate)